# How do I send mail to my google apps mail server from the webserver with the same name (using sendmail) on a shared hosting environment?

Tags: gmail, sendmail

I'm experiencing a similar issue to the one raised in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524224/how-do-i-send-mail-to-my-google-apps-mail-server-from-the-webserver-with-the-same).

sendmail (via PHP) will send an email unless its to an address with the same domain as the server its on.

I understand this is because the sendmail is trying to send the email locally.

I have limited control over the server, as its a shared hosting environment.  I'm pretty much limited to configuring php.ini and modifying the php.  Within these limitations is there a way I can tell sendmail to do what I want?

Failing that, the only other option I see is to use SMTP and have google send the email, which seemed overkill, given that sendmail is there ready to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but if you can, contact your host and ask them to remove your domain name from:

/etc/mail/local-host-names

If you use qmail, remove your domain from

/var/qmail/control/virtualdomains

(locations may vary)